# level=error msg="hcsshim::ImportLayer - failed failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3)" error="hcsshim::ImportLayer

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-11

Trying to build a solution. It builds successfully but ends with an error so I am not able to run the container as it never completes. See error below. I am on windows 11 pro with version 22H2 and build 22621.521. I have been looking at the forums online but nothing has worked for me.

I have managed to complete all the steps in dockerfile successfully with windows version 21H2. I have bought new machine and it comes with the new windows build: 22621.521 and I get the error below.

Any help is much appreciated.

***48 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:02:13.76
ERROR: Service ‘solution’ failed to build: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: time=“2022-09-26T21:14:06+01:00” level=error msg=“hcsshim::ImportLayer - failed failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3)” error=“hcsshim::ImportLayer - failed failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3)” importFolderPath=“C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\hcs861034347” path=“\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\b34083dbe2042a59de9e2a70b2ca36468456a87a5063df36708e55f7b574b5c2”
unexpected EOF***

I have tried followings:

Turned off anti virus real time scanning along with firewall

Tried to add the “storage-opts” property in config file

Tried docker system prune

Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea